# Present UIViewController as UIModalPresentationFormSheet & UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext

Tags: ipad, ios8, uivisualeffectview

How do I present a UITableViewController with a blurred background as a form sheet over the current context?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

   self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:[UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight]];
}
```

It works fine full screen, on iPhones set with `UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext`

But for iPad if I want to display it as a form sheet then I need to set `modalPresentationStyle` to `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`.

How do I set both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I needed to use `UIModalPresentationPopover`for the `modalPresentationStyle` and then you can set the view controllers `popoverPresentationColor` to `clearColor`.

```
 FAGalleryTableViewController *vc = (FAGalleryTableViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];

        if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ) {
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
            vc.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = _storeButton;
            vc.popoverPresentationController.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            vc.popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown;
            vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching so much, this worked for me on iOS10+

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
            //IPAD
            CamVC *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
            [destination setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
            [destination setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];

        }else{
            // IPHONE
            CamVC *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
            destination.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
            destination.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        }
```